# I am not able to create website using jekyll as in command prompt it doesn't show the basic website created at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, atom-editor, jekyll-theme

[image]

[https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg[Command](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg%5BCommand) prompt error! or what?][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJzf4.jpg)

I am not able to create website using jekyll  as in command prompt it doesn't show the basic website created at once.It takes a lot time to analyse the fundamentals of it .Help me in the command prompt error or anything else.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Would love to help but I can't with so little information, can you post the commands that you have tried so far and the output from those commands please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happened to me when I updated to Ruby 3 since `webrick` is not added to the `Gemfile`.

Run `bundle add webrick` then your local `jekyll serve` will works.